# No. of triplets

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, xor

I want to find no. of triplets (i,j,k) in an array of n elements such that the sub sequence

```
Ai xor Ai+1 xor.......Aj-1 = Aj xor Aj+1 xor......Ak
```

where

```
I<j<=k
```

Here, xor is bitwise xor

No. of elements in the array can be upto 10^5

My approach:

I though of brute force but it will fail for sure

I though of sliding window from left and right side but this will also fail as it will be O(n^2)

So I'm unable to think of the algorithm

Can anyone provide a hint? I don't need the code..just the algorithm or even small hints would work

Comment: https://www.codechef.com/AUG19A/problems/KS1 From ongoing contest, anyone please lock this

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been pointed out that it is from an on-going contest.

Answer (score 2):

For all pairs (i,k) where `Ai xor Ai+1 xor ....... Ak = 0` any j (i < j <= k) will be ok. So you just need to find all segments where xor equals zero.

To find these segments calculate prefix xors, and then sort pairs of prefix xor and its position. In sorted array find subarray with equal xor (they will be in a row since the array is sorted). You need to calculate the sum of distances between all pairs.

In this subarray elements are ordered by the position, so each segment (between neighboring nodes) will be used l * r times in this sum where l is the number of elements before left element and r is the number of elements after right element. So you just go through your subarray and calculate this sum using the sum of distances between neighboring elements multiplied by l * r.
This algorithm is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

If a triple (i, j, k) is valid then Ai xor Ai+1 xor ... xor Ak = 0.
So if you find all such pairs (i, k) that Ai xor Ai+1 xor ... xor Ak = 0 you can put j wherever you want between i and k. You can easily calculate number of triples.

To find those pairs in O(n log n) you can use Trie data structure, I believe it was explained well on many websites including Stack Overflow.